# In Django , How to handle multi user types with more than 1 user has access to same content?

Tags: python, django

In a Django Application, I have a model called application.py which is created by a user say "u". I want to list all the application created by the user "u" later, so i may need to add a reference to the model application.py from user.py.

I have one more requirement , as an admin , i need to provide access to any number of users to the same applications. So I assume this can be done with many to many relation.(Since users can access many applications).

Now the question is , is it possible to implement this behavior with user groups ,with one group is responsible for handling one application, so that in a later point of time i can add as many users as needed from the backend to respective groups to manage the same application.?

Which one is better , managing the users using many to many relation with model application.py or relating a group to application.py 
and managing users using groups.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to solve this, but it from a future flexibility point of view this sounds like a Role, Permission and Group relationship:

- `Application`s have a many-to-many relationship to `User`s `through` a `Membership`.
- Each membership would point to a `Role`. That could be hard-coded to start with (just a string like 'admin' or 'viewer').
- This way a `User` can be associated to an `Application` as `viewer` or as an `admin`.
- In the future, to add flexibility, you would have a model `Role` that describes the role (and could be associated to one or more `Permission` models to list the permissions for each role). So `Membership` would have a pointer to `Role` via a ForeignKey.

Check the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) on extra fields on a many-to-many relationship.

There are also packages that solve this problem, e.g. django-permissions and django-role-permission

Comment: Yeah. This looks interesting! One question, the viewer users will be added by admins in backend or through an invite. How easy it is to update the relation to application model when a new user is added to application? Any advantage / drawback in using user group in these cases?

Comment: By "admins" what do you mean, people that have access to the django-admin app? and by user groups what do you mean? the built-in Group model in Django?

Comment: yeah, by admin i mean the someone who has full control like the super user in django admin. and by groups i mean the builtin group model.

Comment: Django's `Group` isn't really suited for this, because you don't want to add a User directly to a group but you want to add a user's membership to a group/role (a user isn't just a viewer, a user is a viewer for a particular application). So this is really something you have to build.

Comment: And yes, you can implement this kind of functionality into the admin site. The Inline admin forms will allow you to specify the role for example, when adding the relationship from `application` to `user` (or vice versa).

Comment: I have come across a library called [`django-organizations`](https://github.com/bennylope/django-organizations) to support multi-user accounts. Is this can be used for my case? what you think? I really don't want to implement the feature with an external library,do you have any information regarding how the  [`django-organizations`](https://github.com/bennylope/django-organizations) works?

Comment: I don't know that package so I can't comment. Read the documentation, and what I always do before choosing a 3rd party package is read the source code (and check that it's regularly maintained).